# cannot set adapter ExpandableRecyclerAdapter android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable Recycler and I fetch data from server and I check the log and I got the data correct, now when I tried to set adapter I got this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object
>   reference

This is my Fragment

```
  private List<GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum> messageslist;
  private GetInboxByUserNameModel getInboxByUserNameModel;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;

  messageslist = new ArrayList<>();
  getInboxByUserNameModel = (GetInboxByUserNameModel) responseObject;
  messageslist = getInboxByUserNameModel.getDATA();
  implementAdapter(messageslist);


  private void implementAdapter(List<GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum> categoriesList) {
        if (categoriesList == null) {
            AlertView.showOneButtonAlert(getActivity(), getActivity(), "", getString(R.string.no_data), getString(R.string.ok), null);
            return;
        }
        if (categoriesList.size() == 0) {
            AlertView.showOneButtonAlert(getActivity(), getActivity(), "", getString(R.string.no_data), getString(R.string.ok), null);
            return;
        }
        mAdapter = new RecipeAdapterForInbox_Test(getActivity(), categoriesList);
        mAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
            @UiThread
            @Override
            public void onParentExpanded(int parentPosition) {
            }

            @UiThread
            @Override
            public void onParentCollapsed(int parentPosition) {
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }
```

and this is my ExpandableRecyclerAdapter

```
 public class RecipeAdapterForInbox_Test extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum, GetInboxByUserNameModel.MESSAGES, ViewHolderParentInbox, ViewHolderChildinbox> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    List<GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum> daTa;

    public RecipeAdapterForInbox_Test(Activity activity, List<GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum> recipeList) {
        super(recipeList);
        this.daTa = recipeList;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @UiThread
    @Override
    public ViewHolderParentInbox onCreateParentViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parentViewGroup, int viewType) {
        View recipeView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_adapter_available_parent, parentViewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolderParentInbox(recipeView, context);
    }

    @UiThread
    @Override
    public ViewHolderChildinbox onCreateChildViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup childViewGroup, int viewType) {
        View ingredientView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_adapter_available_child, childViewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolderChildinbox(ingredientView);
    }

    @UiThread
    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderParentInbox holder, int parentPosition, @NonNull GetInboxByUserNameModel.DATum model) {
        holder.headerNameTextView.setText(model.getbILLINGNUMBER());
    }

    @UiThread
    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderChildinbox holder, int parentPosition, int childPosition, final GetInboxByUserNameModel.MESSAGES model) {
        holder.childTextview.setText(model.getbRIEF());
//        holder.activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                goDialog(model);
//            }
//        });
    }
```

i used debug and the problem is here

```
    super(recipeList);
```

if anyone have any idea about this please help me

Comment: Which library did you use for `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: compile 'com.github.bignerdranch:expandable-recycler-view:v3.0.0-RC1'

Comment: Bro the library you are using is `deprecated`

Comment: hmmm but this is working in other section on my project !!

Comment: debug and check your `recipeList` is null inside `RecipeAdapterForInbox_Test` that's why you are getting this error

Comment: i do this and its not null ,, and i tried recyclerview adapter without Expandable and its working fine ,,,

Comment: the problem is in the adapter and i cannot solve it :(

Comment: your list is not null but what about the child inside the group? please check or loop over the list and check might be childs are null

Comment: post your  `getInboxByUserNameModel = (GetInboxByUserNameModel) responseObject;      `responseObject` object and 
your `getInboxByUserNameModel.getDATA();` code

Comment: thank you i find the problem you are right the child is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are geting this error because of child list inside the group is `null`. Please loop over the `messageslist` and check the group and get the child list.